# Error: Refund amount must equal refund due amount

Tags: drupal, 4.7

Has anyone else had this issue where its not possible to get the refund page to save even though the amount is correct?

[image: Refund amount must equal refund due amount]

**Drupal Error Log**

Notice: Undefined index: event in CRM_Core_Payment_ProcessorForm::preProcess() (line 78 of /****/public_html/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/ProcessorForm.php).

Comment: I'm getting this same error on submitting events where "pay later" is selected as payment method. The page times out - if I select a different payment method the next page loads OK. Does this shed any light on this issue? `Notice: Undefined index: event in CRM_Core_Payment_ProcessorForm::preProcess() (line 78 of xxxxxxxx/sites/all/modules/civicrm/CRM/Core/Payment/ProcessorForm.php).`

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to replicate on dmaster.demo.civicrm.org and if you can replicate it there please create an issue at https://issues.civicrm.org/ and assign it to me (Joe Murray)? Thanks!